# WordPress Plugin won't show up in pluging list

Tags: plugins

I have created several plugins that work and one that wants to hide. The shy plugin is in a folder with the same name as the plugin and the header clearly reflects the plugin name; but the plugin does not appear in the plugin list.

the plugin name is cx-login-logout. The code for the plugin is contained entirely im a file named 'cx-login-logout.php'. This file contains the required commends that identify it as a a WordPress plugin with the name cx-login-logout. Although the folder  and the file are in the wp-content/plugins folder, WordPress doesn't include it in the Plugins tab of the dashboard.

I have other plugins that follow the same pattern and work just fine, but I don't yet spot the pattern.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simple... a single space between the letters "P" and "L" in the line identifying the plugin name. WP could not find the plugin because of the space.